# mod_rewrite not working as internal proxy

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, proxy

I have a site that needs to use mod_rewrite to direct traffic to www.example.com to 123.45.67.89, port 8080, through an internal proxy.  This is the rewrite rule I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://123.45.67.89:8080/$1  [P]
```

When I visit www.example.com/myurl, I receive the following error with a 404:

> The requested URL /myurl was not found on this server.

This redirect works on our dev server, but not on production.  Is there an apache setting that I need to enable in order to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) enabled to use the [`P` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags).

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, this was the correct solution, although I'll add for anyone else viewing the thread in my particular case I needed to enable mod_proxy_http as well.