# Level of obscurity of destination URLs via mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

To achieve a single layer of content delivery security, I'm looking into the possibility of obscuring a resource URL via an .htaccess RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /js/
RewriteRule obscure-alias\.js http://example.com/sensitive.js
```

It would of course be implemented as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="obscure-alias.js"></script>
```

Because this is not a 301 redirect, but rather a routing scenario similar to that of many of our frameworks we used today, would it be safe to say that this RewriteRule adequately obfuscates the actual URL where this resource is located, or:

1. Can the destination URL still be found out via some HTTP header sniffing utility
2. Might a web browser be able to reveal the "Download URL"

I'm going to pre-answer my own questions by saying no to both since the "internal proxy" is taking place on the server-side and not on the client side if I understand it correctly: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html. I just wanted to confirm that when Apache goes to serve the destination URL, that it also isn't passing along information to the user agent what the URL was that it rewrote the original request as.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you specify the redirect target.

If your `http://example.com/` is running on the same server, there will be an internal redirect that is invisible to the client. From the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> **Absolute URL**
>
> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL. To force an external redirect back to the current host, see the [R] flag below.

if the absolute URL points to a remote domain, a header redirect will be performed. A header redirect *is* visible to the client and will reveal the sensitive location.

To make sure no external redirect takes place, specify a relative URL like

```
RewriteRule obscure-alias\.js sensitive.js
```

Note that the sensitive JS file's URL can still be guessed.

To find out whether a request results in a header redirect, log in onto a terminal (eg. on a Linux server) and do

```
wget --server-response http://www.example.com
```

If the first `HTTP/....` line (there may be more than one) is something that begins with a `3xx`, like

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
```

you are looking at a header redirect.

Comment: If I still wanted to accomplish this using remote domains (e.g. CDN hosted), does something like this become an option in conjunction with mod_rewrite?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173571/mod-rewrite-not-working-as-internal-proxy

Comment: @Matt yup, you'd have to proxy it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible using proxy throughput.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html

Also alluded to here as well: [mod_rewrite not working as internal proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173571/mod-rewrite-not-working-as-internal-proxy)